# How to handle circuit breaking mechanism for a single endpoint that calls multiple microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resilience4j

I am currently learning to build microservices using spring-boot. I am stuck at handling circuit breaking mechanism for a controller that calls 2 microservices. How can i handle the circuit breaking mechanism such that if one of the services fails and the other is healthy, i should get a response such that the failed microservice response is default and the other response is valid?

I am using resilience4j for circuit breaking mechanism. This is my code. I shut down department service to simulate one service being down. However, I get an error with message "DEPARTMENT-SERVICE executing GET <<ENDPOINT_OF_DEPARTMENT_SERVICE>>" and errorCode: Internal Server Error.

Everything works fine if both the services are up and running. Also, everything works fine if i add the circuit breaker annotation over the getEmployeeById method. However, doing this means that if one of the services is down, i would have to return default responses for both services despite the other service being up.

NOTE: I am also using api gateway for centralized routing of the requests to various services in case this is useful information.

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private DepartmentApiClient departmentApiClient;
    private OrganizationApiClient organizationApiClient;

    @Override
    public ApiResponseDto getEmployeeById(Long id) {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee", "id", id)
        );

        DepartmentDto departmentDto = getDepartmentInfo(employee.getDepartmentCode());
        OrganizationDto organizationDto = getOrganizationInfo(employee.getOrganizationCode());

        ApiResponseDto apiResponseDto = new ApiResponseDto();
        apiResponseDto.setDepartmentDto(departmentDto);
        apiResponseDto.setEmployeeDto(AutoEmployeeMapper.MAPPER.mapToEmployeeDto(employee));
        apiResponseDto.setOrganizationDto(organizationDto);
        return apiResponseDto;
    }
   
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "DEPARTMENT-SERVICE", fallbackMethod = "getDefaultDepartment")
    public DepartmentDto getDepartmentInfo(String departmentCode) {
        return departmentApiClient.getDepartmentByCode(departmentCode);
    }

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "ORGANIZATION-SERVICE", fallbackMethod = "getDefaultOrganization")
    public OrganizationDto getOrganizationInfo(String organizationCode) {
        return organizationApiClient.getOrganizationByCode(organizationCode);
    }

    public DepartmentDto getDefaultDepartment(Exception ex) {
        DepartmentDto defaultDepartment = new DepartmentDto();
        defaultDepartment.setDepartmentCode("DEFAULT");
        defaultDepartment.setDepartmentName("DEFAULT DEPARTMENT");
        defaultDepartment.setDepartmentDescription("Default Department");
        return defaultDepartment;
    }

    public OrganizationDto getDefaultOrganization(Exception ex) {
        OrganizationDto defaultOrganization = new OrganizationDto();
        defaultOrganization.setOrganizationCode("DEFAULT");
        defaultOrganization.setOrganizationName("DEFAULT ORG");
        defaultOrganization.setOrganizationDescription("Default Organization");
        return defaultOrganization;
    }
}
```

This are the properties for circuit breaker in application.properties file.

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.EMPLOYEE-SERVICE.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.EMPLOYEE-SERVICE.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.EMPLOYEE-SERVICE.minimumNumberOfCalls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.EMPLOYEE-SERVICE.automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.EMPLOYEE-SERVICE.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.EMPLOYEE-SERVICE.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.EMPLOYEE-SERVICE.slidingWindowType=COUNT_BASED
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.EMPLOYEE-SERVICE.slidingWindowSize=10
```

I am not sure if the circuit breaker configurations for the other services should also be here or not. But i tried to run it using the same configuration for the other services as well like the properties below

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.DEPARTMENT-SERVICE.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.DEPARTMENT-SERVICE.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.DEPARTMENT-SERVICE.minimumNumberOfCalls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.DEPARTMENT-SERVICE.automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.DEPARTMENT-SERVICE.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.DEPARTMENT-SERVICE.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.DEPARTMENT-SERVICE.slidingWindowType=COUNT_BASED
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.DEPARTMENT-SERVICE.slidingWindowSize=10

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.ORGANIZATION-SERVICE.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.ORGANIZATION-SERVICE.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.ORGANIZATION-SERVICE.minimumNumberOfCalls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.ORGANIZATION-SERVICE.automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.ORGANIZATION-SERVICE.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.ORGANIZATION-SERVICE.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.ORGANIZATION-SERVICE.slidingWindowType=COUNT_BASED
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.ORGANIZATION-SERVICE.slidingWindowSize=10
```

Comment: hi Monish,  please add configurations used for Resilience4j.
One point to note , the method that is annotated with @CircuitBreaker should not be in the same class as the caller.

Comment: Hi Ajinkya, i have added the configurations for Resilience4j. I didnt understand the 2nd part. Do you mean that the methods annotated using @CircuitBreaker should be in a separate file?

Comment: getDepartmentInfo(), getOrganizationInfo() methods should be in different class